# Aligning the equal signs

Tags: amsmath

How can I make all these equal signs line up properly? I tried the code below and it gave me the result in the picture below. I would really appreciate if someone can help me with this.

```
\documentclass[landscape]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

        \begin{center}
            \begin{aligned}
                e^{-iZ\otimes Z t}|00\rangle & =  e^{i(1\times 1) t}|00\rangle & =e^{it}|00\rangle 
                
                e^{-iZ\otimes Z t}|01\rangle & =  e^{i(1\times -1) t}|01\rangle & =e^{-it}|01\rangle 
                
                e^{-iZ\otimes Z t}|10\rangle & = e^{i(-1\times 1) t}|10\rangle & =e^{-it}|10\rangle 
                
                e^{-iZ\otimes Z t}|11\rangle & = e^{i(-1\times -1) t}|11\rangle & =e^{it}|11\rangle 
            \end{aligned}
        \end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: don't ignore errors! This gives `! Package amsmath Error: \begin{aligned} allowed only in math mode.`  use `\[..\]` not `\begin{center}` or more simply use `\begin{align*}` instead of `aligned`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`aligned` has to be in math mode (eg `\[` not `center`) and the lines separated by `\\`  not a blank line. Don't ignore errors! the PDF is not intended to be usable after any error, it is at best a debugging aid.

But here it is simpler to use `alignat`

[image]

```
\documentclass[landscape]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}


\begin{alignat*}{2}
    e^{-iZ\otimes Z t}|00\rangle & =  e^{i(1\times 1) t}|00\rangle && =e^{it}|00\rangle\\ 
    e^{-iZ\otimes Z t}|01\rangle & =  e^{i(1\times -1) t}|01\rangle && =e^{-it}|01\rangle\\
    e^{-iZ\otimes Z t}|10\rangle & = e^{i(-1\times 1) t}|10\rangle && =e^{-it}|10\rangle\\
  e^{-iZ\otimes Z t}|11\rangle & = e^{i(-1\times -1) t}|11\rangle && =e^{it}|11\rangle
\end{alignat*}


\end{document}
```